# How can I get Vite env variables?

Tags: vuejs3, cypress, vite, quasar-framework, dotenv

I am using Quasar, Vue 3, Vite, Cypress in my project. I don't know how to get `.env` variables (e.g. `VITE_API_URL`) and to set in `cypress.env.json`. Before Vite I used webpack and I know how to do it.

I don't want to define twice same variable, first in `.env` then in `cypress.env.json`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `dotenv` package directly, merging the result in with the `env` section of your cypress config.

**.env**

```js
VITE_API_URL: "http://example.com"
```

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const env = dotenv.config('./.env').parsed

module.exports = defineConfig({
  'component': {
    // component config here
  },
  env: {
    login_url: '/login',
    ...env,                        // merge here with spread operator
  },
});
```

**Settings page in the Cypress runner**

```js
env: {
  login_url: '/login',
  VITE_API_URL: 'http://example.com',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called `cypress-dotenv` for this very purpose. It allows you to share your `.env` file variables between your app and cypress tests.

### Install

```
npm install --save-dev cypress-dotenv

# For typescript
npm install --save-dev @types/cypress-dotenv
```

### Example

Example `.env` file

```
VITE_API_URL=https://vite-api-url.com
```

In your `cypress.config.js`, run the plugin `dotenvCypress()` under `setupNodeEvents()`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import dotenvCypress from 'cypress-dotenv';

export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "vue",
      bundler: "vite",
    },
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return dotenvCypress(config, undefined, true);
    },
  },
});
```

Then in your test:

```js
it('works', () => {
  cy.log(Cypress.env('VITE_API_URL'));
});
```

### Notes

1. `dotenvCypress()` must be returned in `setupNodeEvents()`
2. To get all the env variables from your `.env` file, you have to pass `true` as the third argument to `dotenvCypress()`. Otherwise, only vars prefixed with `CYPRESS_` will be available.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-dotenv

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cypress-plugin-dotenv](https://github.com/MohamadKh75/cypress-plugin-dotenv) to share `.env` files with Cypress app. This plugin is also introduced on [official cypress plugins docs](https://docs.cypress.io/plugins). It works for Vite with react or vue, create-react-app, Turborepo, and many other frameworks and setups.

Installation:

```
npm install cypress-plugin-dotenv
```

Usage:

```
import { dotenv } from 'cypress-plugin-dotenv';
// or
const dotenv = require('cypress-plugin-dotenv');

export default defineConfig({
   e2e: {
     setupNodeEvents: (_, config) => {
       return dotenv(config);
     }
   }
});
```

Now go to your spec file and just use `Cypress.env('YOUR_ENV')`