# How to specify which .env file is used in Cypress Component Tests

Tags: javascript, testing, environment-variables, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

i've been trying to figure out how to specify which .env file to use when running Cypress Component tests for a while now but can't seem to figure it out or find any information about it online.

I've noticed when you mount a Component in Cypress and run some Component Tests, the component will pick up `process.env` variables from the `.env` file by default. However, I would instead like Cypress to pick up `process.env` variables from my `.env.test` file. Does anyone know how to specify which .env file your component should get `process.env` variables from when running component tests?

I am currently just running the following command from my `package.json` file `"test-e2e": "cypress open"`. This opens the Cypress test runner where I can select Component Testing and then select a spec file to run tests against. The component in question uses some `process.env` variables which I can see are being taken from the `.env` file which seems to be the default. I can't find any flags I can add to my npm command to instead tell Cypress to take them from the `.env.test` file instead.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You want to do something like this answer [How can I get Vite env variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75333786/16997707).

Note that the `.env` section of config is outside of component or e2e sections (common to both).

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const env = dotenv.config('./.env.test').parsed

module.exports = defineConfig({
  'component': {
    // component config here
  },
  env: {
    login_url: '/login',
    ...env,                        // merge here with spread operator
  },
});
```